# How does sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression work with insufficient data?

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

To solve a 5 parameter model, I need at least 5 data points to get a unique solution. For x and y data below:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[-0.24155831,  0.37083184, -1.69002708,  1.4578805 ,  0.91790011,
              0.31648635, -0.15957368],
              [-0.37541846, -0.14572825, -2.19695883,  1.01136142,  0.57288752,
              0.32080956, -0.82986857],
              [ 0.33815532,  3.1123936 , -0.29317028,  3.01493602,  1.64978158,
              0.56301755,  1.3958912 ],
              [ 0.84486735,  4.74567324,  0.7982888 ,  3.56604097,  1.47633894,
              1.38743513,  3.0679506 ],
              [-0.2752026 ,  2.9110031 ,  0.19218081,  2.0691105 ,  0.49240373,
              1.63213241,  2.4235483 ],
              [ 0.89942508,  5.09052174,  1.26048572,  3.73477373,  1.4302902 ,
              1.91907482,  3.70126468]])

y = np.array([-0.81388378, -1.59719762, -0.08256274,  0.61297275,  0.99359647, 
             1.11315445])
```

I used only 6 data to fit a 8 parameter model (7 slopes and 1 intercept).

```
lr = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
print(lr.coef_)
array([-0.83916772, -0.57249998,  0.73025938, -0.02065629,  0.47637768,
      -0.36962192,  0.99128474])

print(lr.intercept_)
0.2978781587718828
```

Clearly, it's using some kind of assignment to reduce the degrees of freedom. I tried to look into the source code but couldn't found anything about that. What method do they use to find the parameter of under specified model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reduce the degrees of freedom, it simply finds a solution to the least squares problem `min sum_i (dot(beta,x_i)+beta_0-y_i)**2.` For example, in the non-sparse case it uses the [linalg.lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) module from scipy. The default solver for this optimization problem is the `gelsd` LAPACK driver. If 
`A= np.concatenate((ones_v, X), axis=1)`
is the augmented array with ones as its first column, then your solution is given by

```
x=numpy.linalg.pinv(A.T*A)*A.T*y
```

Where we use the pseudoinverse precisely because the matrix may not be of full rank. Of course, the solver doesn't actually use this formula but uses singular value Decomposition of `A` to reduce this formula.

Comment: So, there could be infinitely many solutions? It just returns the first local minima it gets?

Comment: While there could be infinitely many solutions to the optimization problem, the pseudoinverse is uniquely defined by your SVD decomposition, so you always get the same x from the above expression if you use the gelsd solver.